# Why does this closure example work incorrect?

Tags: javascript

I've seen examples of closure and I thought I understand them, until I decided to do this:

```
var f = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    f[i] = function foo(a) {
        var h = i;
        function bar() {
            console.log(h);
        }
        if (a == 1)
            bar();
    }
}

for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    console.log(f[j](1));
}
```

The output is this:

```
2
2
```

When I thought it would be `0, 1` since I created an outer function `foo` where I store `i` in the variable `h`
Can someone explain what happens here and why those `setTimeout` examples work correct?

Comment: You have no `setTimeout` calls?  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) is highly related, possibly a duplicate.

Comment: You're only assigning `i` to `h` when the function is actually called. At that time `i` is already 2.

Comment: @Yoshi Ok now I got it. Was easy actually. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For the desired output update your code to following

```
var f = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  f[i] = (function(i){ 
              return function foo(a) {
                 var h = i;
                 function bar() {
                     console.log(h);
                 }
                 if (a == 1)
                    bar();
             }
         })(i);
}

for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    console.log(f[j](1));
}
```